# Why does Rendering in Premiere Pro CC 2015 crashes whole system?

Tags: video, cpu, crash, overheating, adobe-premiere

I don't know if this is hardware or software problem because I've pretty good configuration and the system is crashing due to CPU overheating.

For hardware, I've 16gigs RAM and an AMD FX 8320. That should be enough to do this job.

I'm rendering a 3-4 minutes of video in H.264 in YouTube 1080p quality. The video clips I'm working on are shot in 1080p @ 30fps. The rendering process upto half-way. Somewhere between 50-60% it shuts down the PC abruptly.

---

#### What I've already tried doing

- Cleaning media cache database
- Changing the renderer to **Software Only** from **GPU Acceleration *(CUDA)***.

I would like to add that I haven't tried exporting via Adobe Media Encoder because I'm not able to install it at this point.

Can anybody help me resolve my problem?

Comment: If it is crashing due to overheating then you need to improve your cooling system.

Comment: Is this the only way? Does every user using Premiere shall improve cooling system?

Comment: Unless you can find a thousand threads of people saying that their machine overheats if, *and only if*, using Premiere then I think it's safe to say that you will have this problem with other similarly demanding programs.  Lots of people say they have problems when playing games but that's because the only heavy load their machine sees *is* games and there are many other programs that can cause the problem.  Find out *what* is overheating and stop it.  If nothing is overheating (that you can see), then it could be a power supply or motherboard issue.

Comment: Programs for checking temperatures: [Coretemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) for CPU, [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) for GPUs, [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) for everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe your CPU is overheating, you could reduce the CPU usage from 100% to say, 90%. To do so, go to:

- Run
- Type in `control panel`
- *Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings*.
- Search for *Processor power management > Maximum processor state*.
- Change the value to something below 100%.